# execl failing to find vim

Tags: c, exec

In my C program on Linux, I fork off a child process and call `vim` on a file.  The line is

```
execl(editor,path,NULL);
```

where `editor` is a `const char*` pointing to `"vim"` and `path` is a `const char*` pointing to `"../grr/engine/nfaRuntime.c"`.

Under strace, I see

```
[pid  2022] execve("vim", ["../grr/engine/nfaRuntime.c"], 0x7ffc32f38ea8 /* 28 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

However, vim is installed on my computer (and within `PATH`) and the specified file does exist.  I also have read access to it.  I have confirmed, via `getcwd`, that my program is running inside the `grr` directory.

Comment: Answer to the next question you are going to ask:  When calling an executable, the first argument should by convention be the name of the executable, so when using the `exec`-family of functions, you should write: `execl(editor, editor, path, NULL);`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execl` does not search the paths given by `PATH`. `execlp` does.